# Imported Obj "Tears" visually but not in the mesh

Tags: import, obj

Been having an issue with certain objects modelled in Sketchup and exported as Obj into Blender. On import faces occasionally have this bizarre visual tear that I cannot seem to get rid of.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/2osfH5o]

A Redditor suggested I turn on autosmoothing (it is already on) and clear the custom normals. This instantly fixes the look of the model - until you go to texture paint, and which case the problem endures (this look slightly different because they were taken on several models wherein I tried to fix the problem by re-exporting the sketchup original with minor changes to the model).

If you go to paint, the 'tear' remains and seems to have carried over into the UV Unwrap (which I make AFTER clearing the custom normals)

[image: https://imgur.com/a/wyfjXVv]

Furthermore, this visual tear seems unrelated to edges or faces:

[image: https://imgur.com/a/wF69jOr]

What's going on and is there any way I can fix it?

Comment: Hi, please consider posting the images inline in the future. It makes it faster and easier to understand your issue for all the good people who might be willing to help you.

Comment: For future reference could you explain what doing that looks like?